# What is wrong with this MySQL Trigger?

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I am trying to write a trigger that ranks all the entries in a table from 1 to 10 (with the maximum value having rank 10, the minimum value having rank 1, and all others are assigned integer values in between). Here is the trigger code:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER risks_before_insert
BEFORE INSERT ON risks
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

DECLARE max_cost double; #previous maximum expected_cost in project
DECLARE min_cost double; #previous minimum expected_cost in project
DECLARE slope double; #slope for prioritizing functioN

SELECT MAX(expected_cost), MIN(expected_cost) INTO max_cost, min_cost FROM view_risks; #GET EXTREME VALUES FROM TABLE, STORE IN MEMORY

/*
Update Priority Monetary Rankings
*/
IF (max_cost IS NULL OR min_cost IS NULL) THEN #check for empty table
    SET NEW.priority_monetary = 10;
ELSE IF ((NEW.expected_cost <= max_cost) AND (NEW.expected_cost >= min_cost)) THEN #NEW VALUE DOES NOT CHANGE TABLE EXTREMES
    IF (max_cost – min_cost = 0) THEN
        SET NEW.priority_monetary = 10;
    ELSE
        SET slope = 9 / (max_cost – min_cost);
        SET NEW.priority_monetary = slope * (NEW.expected_cost - min_cost) + 1;
    END IF;
ELSE IF (NEW.expected_cost > max_cost) THEN
    SET NEW.priority_monetary = 10;
    SET slope = 9 / (NEW.expected_cost – min_cost);
    UPDATE TABLE risks SET priority_monetary = slope * (expected_cost - min_cost) + 1;
ELSE #NEW VALUE CORRESPONDS TO A MINIMUM
    SET NEW.priority_monetary = 1;
    SET slope = 9 / (max_cost – NEW.expected_cost);
    UPDATE TABLE risks SET priority_monetary = slope * (expected_cost – NEW.min_cost) + 1;
END IF;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

However, I am getting the following error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '– min_cost); SET NEW.priority_monetary = slope * (NEW.expected_cost - min_cost' at line 22
```

Can anyone explain what is wrong? For your reference, my ranking algorithm is described by the following function with constants maxval and minval:

> Rank(x) = 1 + slope(x - minval), where slope = 9/(maxval - minval).

Comment: your indentation is off too, which doesn't make this fun to read.  please fix the indentation, **Here and in your code on your machine**

Comment: The indentation on my machine was correct. I'm not sure why it got screwed up when I posted it here, but I have fixed it.

Comment: what data type is `priority_monetary`?  when you perform multiplication it returns a `BIGINT`

Answer (score 1):

you should be checking for an out of range exception.  it should never equal 0. if it does the query will fail and hose up the database.

you should be checking `maxval` and `minval` to make sure that `maxval - minval` does not equal `0` before setting the `slope` to `9/(maxval - minval)`

if you run this

```
SET slope = 9 / (max_cost – min_cost);
```

and it tries to set `slope` to `9/0`  it will crash.

Comment: Thanks, I made that correction. I still get the same error though. I have updated the code above.

Comment: The Error Message changed. you should look at posting a new question maybe

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with Triggers, but I think that your issue is in the `SET` statement.

I am thinking that you cannot set `NEW.priority_monetary`

I haven't seen any Syntax like that for SQL before, but I am still new to the game, but I am guessing that if you drop the `NEW.` and just set `priority_monetary` then the error will probably go away

Comment: You can SET like this, in fact you have to otherwise it will be evaluated as a boolean condition. See examples here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/trigger-syntax.html